# Mapping Jersey URI Template in Filter

Tags: java, rest, jersey, requestfiltering

I have what I feel should be a quick question, but perhaps I'm not too sure on the proper terminology to be searching under for the answer to this question.

I currently am running Jetty 9.2 web server with Jersey 2.0. I successfully have been able to map url templates to requests as seen below:

```
@GET
@Path("/box/{boxId}/container/{containerId}/")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String GetBoxContainer(@PathParam("boxId") int boxId,
        @PathParam("containerId") String containerId) {
    ....
}
```

I have also put a filter in front as seen below:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        System.out.println("Hello Authentication filter!!!");
    }
}
```

Is there a similar way I can do a similar `@Path("...")` inside of the filter? It would be the same authentication argument requirement for GET/POST/PUT etc... Authentication of this resource is dependent on boxId and containerId.

I think something along the lines of [Name Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641345/jersey-request-filter-only-on-certain-uri) is what I'm looking for, but not positive.