# How to exclude some url from jersey filter?

Tags: java, web-services, filter, jersey

I've used jersey to create webservices. I've created request filter using `ContainerRequestFilter`. I've gone through  [Jersey Request Filter only on certain URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641345/jersey-request-filter-only-on-certain-uri) question but I want to exclude filter for some urls only.

```
@Provider
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

// business logic

   }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125296/can-i-exclude-some-concrete-urls-from-url-pattern-inside-filter-mapping

Comment: I am talking about jersey filter not servlet filter.

Comment: Cássio Mazzochi Molin's response will work, however, use filterchain.doFilter() as return; aborts the request

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Name binding filters

Instead of excluding URIs from a *global filter*, you could consider using a *name binding filter* to select the endpoints your filter will be bound to.

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38523942/1426227) for some examples with name binding filters.

### Global filters

If you are still happy with the global filter approach, you could consider using the [`UriInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) interface to get details about the requested URI. Use one of the following approaches to get an instance of [`UriInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html):

1. Using the [`@Context`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation:

   ```
   @Provider
   public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

       @Context
       private UriInfo info;

       @Override
       public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

2. Getting it from the [`ContainerRequestContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html):

   ```
   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
       UriInfo info = requestContext.getUriInfo();
       ...
   }
   ```

Once you have the `UriInfo` instance, you'll have access to a bunch of methods that may be useful:

- [`getAbsolutePath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getAbsolutePath--): Get the absolute path of the request.
- [`getBaseUri()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getBaseUri--): Get the base URI of the application.
- [`getMatchedResources()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getMatchedResources--): Get a read-only list of the currently matched resource class instances.
- [`getMatchedURIs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getMatchedURIs--): Get a read-only list of URIs for matched resources.
- [`getPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPath--): Get the path of the current request relative to the base URI as a string.
- [`getPathSegments()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathSegments--): Get the path of the current request relative to the base URI as a list of [`PathSegment`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html).
- [`getRequestUri()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getRequestUri--): Get the absolute request URI including any query parameters.
- [`relativize(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#relativize-java.net.URI-): Relativize a URI with respect to the current request URI.
- [`resolve(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#resolve-java.net.URI-): Resolve a relative URI with respect to the base URI of the application.

For more details, check the [`UriInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) documentation.

If the requested URI does not match the URIs you want to apply the filter to, simply use a `return` instruction:

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    UriInfo info = requestContext.getUriInfo();
    if (!info.getPath().contains("secured")) {
        return;
    }
}
```

### Dynamic binding

Another approach is *dynamic binding*. It allows you to assign filters and interceptors to the resource methods in a dynamic manner. Name binding, mentioned above, uses a static approach and changes to binding require source code change and recompilation. With dynamic binding you can implement code which defines bindings during the application initialization time.

The following example extracted from the [Jersey documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) shows how to implement dynamic binding:

```java
@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("too-much-data")
    public String getVeryLongString() {
        String str = ... // very long string
        return str;
    }
}
```

```java
// This dynamic binding provider registers GZIPWriterInterceptor
// only for HelloWorldResource and methods that contain
// "VeryLongString" in their name. It will be executed during
// application initialization phase.
public class CompressionDynamicBinding implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
        if (HelloWorldResource.class.equals(resourceInfo.getResourceClass())
                && resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getName().contains("VeryLongString")) {
            context.register(GZIPWriterInterceptor.class);
        }
    }
}
```

The binding is done using the provider which implements the [`DynamicFeature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/DynamicFeature.html) interface. The interface defines one `configure` method with two arguments, [`ResourceInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) and [`FeatureContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/FeatureContext.html).

[`ResourceInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) contains information about the resource and method to which the binding can be done. The configure method will be executed once for each resource method that is defined in the application. In the example above the provider will be executed twice, once for the `getHello()` method and once for `getVeryLongString()` (once the `resourceInfo` will contain information about `getHello()` method and once it will point to `getVeryLongString()`).

If a dynamic binding provider wants to register any provider for the actual resource method it will do that using provided [`FeatureContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/FeatureContext.html) which extends JAX-RS Configurable API. All methods for registration of filter or interceptor classes or instances can be used. Such dynamically registered filters or interceptors will be bound only to the actual resource method. In the example above the `GZIPWriterInterceptor` will be bound only to the method `getVeryLongString()` which will cause that data will be compressed only for this method and not for the method `getHello()`.

Note that filters and interceptors registered using dynamic binding are only additional filters run for the resource method. If there are any name bound providers or global providers they will still be executed.

---

For more details, check the [Jersey documentation about filters and interceptors](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html).

Comment: Which Jersey's version is this for?

Comment: @RicardoVigatti Jersey 2.x.

Answer (score 3):

Using @NameBinding may be the most elegant approach, but if you just want to exclude a single resource and apply the filter on all others you have to remember putting the binding annotation on all resources. In this case you can use `ContainerRequestContext.getUriInfo().getMatchedResources()` to check whether the target resource has been matched. This is better than hard-coding a path that might change.

The example below will apply the filter logic on all resources but StatusResource:

```
public class CorsContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext req) {
        if (!matchesStatusResource(req)) {
            // filter logic
        }
    }

    private boolean matchesStatusResource(ContainerRequestContext req) {
        List<Object> matchedResources = req.getUriInfo().getMatchedResources();
        for (Object matchedResource : matchedResources) {
            if (matchedResource instanceof StatusResource) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

As mentioned by others Dynamic bindings can be used instead but it is quite ugly as it is not obvious that the filter wouldn't be applied to all resources.

Comment: It should be noted that `.getMatchedResources` won't work for filters that have the `@PreMatching` annotation as the `filter` method would run **before** any resource matching has been made.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can check the URL pattern and abort the request, using [getUri](https://jax-rs.github.io/apidocs/2.1/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getUriInfo--)

Something like the following

```
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

       String path =    requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath();
       if(path.contains("admin")){
          requestContext.abortWith(new Response());
       }

   }
}
```

https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9339

Comment: Be aware that the `return` instruction won't abort the request, as you have mentioned in your answer. It will abort the filter execution. To abort the request, an exception can be thrown or the `ContainerRequestContext#abortWith(Response)` method can be invoked.

Comment: The `ContainerRequestContext#getUri()` method does not exist. It should be  `ContainerRequestContext#getUriInfo()`.

Comment: Name binding is better solution compared to 'hard' coding the url in the filter. This class/method would need to be updated each time a new url need to be added.