# ResourceInfo not injected into spring managed jersey filter

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jersey-2.0, servlet-filters

I am having problems injecting the ResourceInfo into my jersey filter. The annotation @Context doesn't seem to work properly when having a spring managed filter instance.

What I found is this:
[Jersey Request Filter only on certain URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641345/jersey-request-filter-only-on-certain-uri)

The second goal is quite similar to my situation.

DynamicFeature:

```
@Provider
public class HttpCacheConfigDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {
    private final DefaultHttpCacheFilter defaultHttpCacheFilter;
    private final HttpCacheFilter httpCacheFilter;

    @Autowired
    public HttpCacheConfigDynamicFeature(DefaultHttpCacheFilter defaultHttpCacheFilter, HttpCacheFilter httpCacheFilter) {
        this.defaultHttpCacheFilter = defaultHttpCacheFilter;
        this.httpCacheFilter = httpCacheFilter;
    }
...
```

Filter:

```
@Component
public class HttpCacheFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(HttpCacheFilter.class);

    private final ConfigurationController configurationController;

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Autowired
    public HttpCacheFilter(ConfigurationController configurationController) {
        this.configurationController = configurationController;
}
...
```

The resource info is always null.

What I do now is to change my dynamicFeature a little to that:

```
@Provider
public class HttpCacheConfigDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {
    private final DefaultHttpCacheFilter defaultHttpCacheFilter;
    private final ConfigurationController configurationController;

    @Autowired
    public HttpCacheConfigDynamicFeature(DefaultHttpCacheFilter defaultHttpCacheFilter, ConfigurationController configurationController) {
        this.defaultHttpCacheFilter = defaultHttpCacheFilter;
        this.configurationController = configurationController;
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext featureContext) {
        if (hasHttpCacheConfigAnnotation(resourceInfo)) {
            featureContext.register(new HttpCacheFilter(configurationController, resourceInfo), 50);
        } else {
            featureContext.register(defaultHttpCacheFilter, 51);
        }
    }
```

Maybe you know a more elegant way to achieve my goals.

Thanks!

Christoph

Answer (score 0):

In normal cases it would work, as Jersey would still inject it. But there is a known issue with the DynamicFeature and registering instances. If you register it as a class (i.e. `register(HttpCacheFilter.class)`), then injections will work.

In your case, I don't see any reason you need to manually pass the `ConfigurationController` to the `HttpCacheFilter` that you instantiate. If you just register the class like in the previous example, it will automatically be injected.

Also (not tested) but I think you can even clean it up and just use `@Inject` on the constructor of the filter. Then you can have both the `ResourceInfo` and the `ConfigurationController` both as constructor arguments. Not a big deal, but to me it's looks cleaner just having one injection point. Like I said, I didn't test it, but I'm pretty sure it will work. `@Inject` and `@Context` are pretty much interchangeable with Jersey, and you can also use `@Inject` for Spring components in Jersey, so I would imagine that it just works.